# I am trying to find out the difference between ducharse and ducharte. When I google ducharte all of the sites changes ducharte to duchar

Tags: vocabulario-técnico

I have the same issue with levantarse and levantarte. And this acts like I am spelling them wrong. I am beginning to wonder if it is a Duolingo thing. Please keep in mind that it has been a long time since english class.

Answer (score 3):

Ducharse (reflexive)

Yo voy a duchar**me** / Tu vas a duchar**te** / El va a duchar**se**

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/duchar

Duchar

https://dle.rae.es/duchar

**Ducharse**

https://conjugador.reverso.net/conjugacion-espanol-verbo-ducharse.html

Existen diferencias entre **ducharse** y **bañarse**, pero no entre duchar**te** y duchar**se**, ya que pertenecen al mismo verbo en segunda y tercera persona respectivamente. Yo voy a duchar**te** (a ti) / El va a duchar**se**. Verbo reflexivo duchar**se**.

There are differences between **showering** and **bathing**, but not between duchar**te** and duchar**se**, since they belong to the same verb in the second and third person respectively. I am going to shower (you) / He is going to shower. (Yo voy a duchar**te** (a ti) / El va a duchar**se**. Verbo reflexivo duchar**se**.) Reflexive verb to shower

[image]

Pronombres Reflexivos

https://www.upb.edu.co/es/central-blogs/ortografia/pronombres-reflexivos

[image]

Diccionario panhispánico de dudas

**SE**

*d) Componente de las formas de tercera persona de los verbos pronominales. Hay verbos (arrepentirse, quejarse, etc.) que se construyen en todas sus formas con un pronombre átono reflexivo, que no desempeña ninguna función sintáctica en la oración; la forma que corresponde a las terceras personas es se: El moribundo se arrepintió de sus pecados; Los clientes se quejaron del trato recibido. Algunos verbos son exclusivamente pronominales, como arrepentirse, adueñarse, resentirse, etc., y otros adoptan determinados matices significativos o expresivos en los usos pronominales, como ir(se), dormir(se), salir(se), etc.: Juan (se) salió de la reunión. También se construyen necesariamente con el pronombre átono las acepciones pronominales que corresponden a la llamada «voz media», con la que se expresa que al sujeto le ocurre lo denotado por el verbo, sin que haya causa conocida o sin que esta importe, a veces por tratarse de una acción inherente a la naturaleza del sujeto: El barco se hundió; En primavera los campos se llenan de flores.*

> d) Component of the third person forms of pronominal verbs. There are
> verbs (repent, complain, etc. **arrepentirse, quejarse**, etc.)  that are built in all their forms with
> a reflexive atonic pronoun, which does not play any syntactic function
> in the sentence; the form that corresponds to third persons is se: The
> dying man repented of his sins; Customers complained about the
> treatment received. Some verbs are exclusively pronominal, such as
> repent, own, resent, etc. (arrepentirse, adueñarse, resentirse), and
> others adopt certain significant or
> expressive nuances in pronominal uses, such as ir(se), sleep(se),
> (dormir(se), salir(se), etc.)
> salir(se), etc.: Juan ( se) salió de la reunión / left the meeting. **The
> pronominal meanings**
> that correspond to the so-called «middle voice» are also necessarily
> built with the unstressed pronoun, with which it is expressed that
> what is denoted by the verb happens to the subject, without there
> being a known cause or without this mattering, sometimes because it is
> an action inherent to the nature of the subject: The ship sank; In
> spring the fields are filled with flowers.

**SE**

https://www.rae.es/dpd/se

Comment: Why do you get into all that? The first line was enough, basically. Also, they we say reflexive verbs in English.

Answer (score 0):

Duchar is to shower (something or somebody). Ducharse adds the pronoun se and so means to shower yourself. In English we do not normally bother to say that unless it is ambiguous. You would just say you are going to shower and it would be assumed you are going to shower yourself. If you are speaking to someone you normally address with the familiar you and ask them whether they want to shower then you would add the pronoun form te not se.

Comment: The idiomatic translation of ducharse is to take a shower. In Spanish, the verbs ducharse and bañarse are reflexive, but not in English: take a shower or a bath.

Answer (score 0):

ducharse in Spanish is a reflexive verb. [verbo pronominal]

to take a shower is ducharse.

ducharte would refer to the second person pronoun used with the infinitive.

¿No vas a ducharte? Aren't you going to take a shower?

You have to google an actual sentence and/or put the search term in quotation marks:

"vas a ducharte por la mañana?"
"ducharte por la mañana".

When googling something that is not an infinitive form, it's best to use a phrase in quotes.

Comment: Message to downvoters: tsk, tsk, tsk.